# making cells in collection view dynamic and add images to them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, collectionview

[image: cells containing user pic and button to add pic]I want to upload pictures for different user types. So for user type 1..I want to create a collection view displaying 3 cells containing 3 options to add and display pic and for other users, 2 cells each. Like in above pic, 2 cells were created for userType = 3. So far Im able to create required number of cells according to users but haven't been able to upload pictures in any of them. I already have separate imagePicker delegate method to upload pic somewhere else but that's a static pic. I want to upload pics in these dynamically created cells. So if user = 3, Return 2 cells containing image view and button (Document) to add pic. Here's my code so far:

```
let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
        
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            let userType = typeOfUser //typeOfUser = 1,2,3
            var cellNumber = 0
            if userType == "2" {
                cellNumber = 3 //to return 3 cells for userType 2
            } else {
                cellNumber = 2 //to return 2 cells for userType 1 and 3
            }
            return cellNumber
        }
        
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! DocumentCollectionViewCell
            if userType == "2" {
                for index in 0 ..< 3 {  // for user = "2", 3 cells required so I used forloop < 3  
                   let imageData:NSData = cell.userPic.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 60)! as NSData //compress image
                   let base64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)   //store image in base64
    
               //code below to pass base64 to image view and give it some id(stuck at creating logic for that)
               
            }  
         }
       return cell
}
```

This code does return correct number of cells with 3 empty image views with add picture button below each of them for typeOfUser = "2" as required but how to make button below each imageView add 1 picture at a time to one cell? Make each button use that imagePicker delegate and open photo library to add pic in "n" cells for respective user types?

Like how can I add picture in above image by clicking Document button below 1st image and then second image and if some other user, add as much images I want to add by clicking button below each image view created in no matter how many cells are returned?

This is all I want in short:

> 1. For user = 3
> 2. return 2 cells like above image
> 3. add pics by clicking document button below each image
> 4. for other users do same for different number of cells.

Comment: I hope I am not stating the obvious but the `cellForItemAt` function is returning an empty(unpopulated) cell. it's also not clear what the `for` loop is doing with the base64 data. Lastly the `indexPath` is not being used to retrieve any associated data - that indicates what cell you should be populating and returning. Maybe there's more code? Can you update and clarify the question? [This Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/18895088-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started) may help.

Comment: Still not sure the question is clear but this - *return 2 cells like above image* - sounds funky. The function returns 1 cell, not 2 cells. So that will be called for each indexPath in each section. For example; this this `numberOfItemsInSection` returns 3 because there are three items then this `collectionView:cellForItemAt` will be called three times; once for each cell. Each cell will need to be populated with the image or whatever and returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through delegate.

1. Create Protocol:

```swift
protocol ButtonDelegate  {
    // Define expected delegate functions
    func cellButtonClicked(tag: Int, indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

2. Confirm this Protocol in class where you want to take action:

```swift
extension ViewController: ButtonDelegate {
    
func cellButtonClicked(tag: Int, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
//implement Logic to open ImageLibrary, you have indexPath available here
}
}
```

3. Inside `PhotoCell` create delegate instance and info needed for delegate method:

```swift
class PhotoCell... {
    var cellButtonDelegate:  ButtonDelegate?
    var indexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath()
}
```

4. In `ViewController:func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` add these lines:

```swift
cell.indexPath = indexPath
cell.ImageButton.tag = 0 // tag to identify userNumber
cell.cellButtonDelegate = self
```

5. In button action inside `PhotoCell`, inform delegate function:

```swift
cellButtonDelegate.cellButtonClicked(tag: sender.tag, indexPath: self.indexPath)
```